# Connection refused when calling endpoints from android client

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-endpoints

My android app uses google endpoints as a scalable backend solution. However, I am having trouble calling it from the android client.

I call an async task class from an activity and in the async task class call the endpoints method. In this case the default `sayHi()` method is called and the message should be displayed in a toast using the `onPostExecute(String result)` method.

However when I run the app module in the emulator, this error appears in the toast:

```
failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080) after 20000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Here is the code that calls the async task from the activity:

```
Profile profile = new Profile(firstName, lastName, birthday);
new EndpointTask(). new SaveProfileTask(profile, this).execute();
```

Here is the async task class:

```
public class EndpointTask {

    public class SaveProfileTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private final String LOG_TAG = SaveProfileTask.class.getSimpleName();
        private MyApi mApi;
        private Profile mProfile;
        private Context mContext;

        public SaveProfileTask(Profile profile, Context context) {
            mProfile = profile;
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (mApi == null) {
                MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                        // options for running against local devappserver
                        // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                        // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                        .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                        .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                            @Override
                            public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                                abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                            }
                        });
                mApi = builder.build();
            }

            try {
                return mApi.sayHi(mProfile.getFirstName()).execute().getData();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ERROR: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of this is taken from the github repo [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints). Which is part of the official android documentation for hooking up the client with the backend for google app engine.

Why is this error occurring and how can it be fixed?

Thanks guys, happy coding.

Comment: Hey Tom,  can you confirm that you've started the backend locally before you tried to call it from your Android app?

Comment: Yes I have ran it locally and it worked fine. (The default sayHello)

Comment: ah so are you trying to run it against your live app engine instance now?

If so you need to a) make sure you deploy, and b) change your rootUrl server from 10.0.2.2 to your App Engine project url.

Comment: When I run the backend module and test it locally on localhost:8080 in my browser it works fine. But when testing locally on the android emulator and calling the endpoint functions from the android client side it gives the error as described in my question.

Comment: Can you see if you access 10.0.2.2:8080 from the emulator browser?

Comment: I am unable to access 10.0.2.2:8080 in the emulator browser when the app is running.